# git diff ignore moved

Tags: git, diff

I need to diff two commits **removing ALL white-space** and code moves. So when I use:

```
git diff --stat COMMIT1 COMMIT2
```

I get: `67 files changed, 3615 insertions(+), 5534 deletions(-)`

and when I use:

```
git diff --stat --ignore-space-at-eol -b -w --ignore-blank-lines COMMIT1 COMMIT2
```

I get `67 files changed, 885 insertions(+), 2655 deletions(-)`.

This still accounts for moved code and when I pass `--color-moved` to the `git diff` command,  it correctly detects the moves and marks them with different colors (`zebra`).

**My question**: Is there a way to ignore the moves using `git diff` so that I can leverage the `--stat` of `git diff`? Something like `--ignore-moved`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the moved-code detector is a separate blob of code that applies only to `git diff` displays; `git diff --stat` does not use it.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the info!